# Website showing increase visit rate in Google Analytics for those keywords which are not even listed in Google

Tags: google-analytics, search-engines

I have a strange scenario. My website's Google Analytics results are showing the increase rate in visits for those keywords (using Google Organic) which are not listed in Google.

I can see in Google Analytics that 500 users visit my site using XYZ Keyword by Google Organic search. But if I search XYZ in the Google search engine I can't even see my website in the first 20 pages.

How could it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Check with [Google Webmaster Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Webmaster_Tools) and "your site on the web" -> "search queries". If they show up there, then yes, your site does get found for these terms, maybe not on *google.com*, but on another country domain (*google.de* or *google.co.uk*), so you didn't see it in your small scale test.

If they don't show up on Google Webmaster Tools then there is the chance that another site used your Google Analytics id (there isn't any tracking fail I haven't seen before...) then you can use [Blekko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blekko) to find this (it has some advanced find sites with the same tracking features).

Comment: Unfortunately, Blekko and the mentioned feature does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Google shows different results for different countries. Check which countries these users came from, and then log on to a web proxy and surf Google from that location. In that country you may be ranking on top...

Another option is that it is bots that are scanning the Internet...

Comment: Yeah, google is often localized.  Especially for keywords that are very location specific, of course, so that's something to consider.